# Recorded the live streaming video in portrait mode but in youtube in browser displayed landscape mode

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I successfully integrate the live streaming video in my application. I recorded the live stream video in portrait mode. but the live streaming video displayed in you tube landscape How to solve this issue?

Please see the below link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXv5fKY8AFM

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Streaming-Youtube-Videos-with-YouTubePlayerView), if you want to force the video to landscape mode, you need to add the `screenOrientation` flag inside your `Activity` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity
  android:name=".SampleActivity"
  android:screenOrientation="landscape">
</activity>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please read the question again.I  record the livestream video in portrait but in receiver side displayed in landscape  mode.